# "OSError: array allocation size too large" when stroke_width is greater than 1

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a snippet of code that roughly evaluates to this:

```
 draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_layer)

 font = ImageFont.truetype(
     f"{fonts_dir}/{config['round_font']}", config["round_size"]
 )

 draw.text(
    (274, 584),
    "texttext",
    '#000000',
    font=font,
    anchor="mm",
    stroke_width=1,
    stroke_fill="#000000",
)
```

Whenever stroke_width is greater than 1, the script (immediately?) crashes with "OSError: array allocation size too large". My machine has 16 gbs of ram, which sounds like more than enough for such a task. The font that I'm using is "Brush King".

Does anyone have any idea? Alternatives are also much appreciated.

Comment: I can’t test anything right now so I’m not sure exactly what the stroke width does. According to the pillow docs [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) the default value for stroke_width is 0, and I’m not really sure how that makes sense. What does it look like with a stroke width of 0?

Comment: Right, the doc doesn't seem to be too clear about this. The stroke_width parameter refers to the "outline" of the text, like a border. The stroke_width parameter regulates how thick it is, and 0 means no outline/border, basically.

Comment: So I've done a little experimenting and it seems that if you use `font = ImageFont.load_default()` to use the default font, the `stroke_width` parameter can be any value, including a string or float, and I can't see any difference at all. When I use the brush king truetype font, any truthy value given to that paramenter causes the OS Error. I'm not sure what you wanted this for, but I think only someone familiar with pillow could solve this. I think the best would be to raise a bug report on the pillow github, since you might get some answers there.

Comment: Please use proper, internationally agreed SI units. GB=gigabytes. Gb=gigabits. gb=?

Comment: Please make sure your [mcve] is minimal and RUNNABLE.

Comment: If you are using a weird, non-standard font, please leave a link showing where it can be downloaded. The general idea is that if you want folks to help you, make it **easy** for them, else they won't bother. Thank you.

Comment: I got the font I used for testing [here](https://fontsfree.net/brush-king-font-download.html) and modified [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text) example from the pillow docs if anyone wants to reproduce what is being described here. I'm pretty sure this is a pillow issue, but I don't know enough about truetype fonts or pillow to really go deeper into why this is happening.

Comment: I tried the same thing with [this](https://www.fontspace.com/chrusty-rock-font-f35152) font and it seems to work fine, so I think the font you are trying to use is somehow broken, possibly it is just too large for pillow to handle, so the best solution here I think would be to try a similar font and see if you can make it work.

Comment: @Cmd858 thank you so much for your effort, I will try my luck by opening an issue on their Github page. Have a great day :)